# How can I get an update notification (e.g. via email) when a Firefox theme is updated?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, themes, notifications

I love Chrome's style but I like to develop web pages using Firebug.

I'm looking at a Firefox theme named [Chromifox Extreme](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/chromifox-extreme/) but it says that it's not available for Firefox 8.0.

I want to be updated as soon as it is available via email. How can I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the add-on [developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/97358/) to update you when a new version is available. No doubt he's getting tons of such requests, but I assume you can increase your chances of receiving an answer by contributing the $2.99 he asks for on the add-on page.

Alternatively, you can use a service like [ChangeDetect](http://www.changedetect.com/) to alert you to changes on the web page, assuming a new version will be announced.

Comment: Nice ChangeDetect

Comment: Don't like `ChangeDetect` since mornitoring https:// require payment God no :)

Comment: So: no contribution to developer, and no paying for online services... :)

Comment: @TTG I'm sorry :) I'll pay for higher feature not the https// protocol

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [Google Alert](http://www.google.com/alerts) with query `"chromifox extreme" "firefox 8"`. It will automatically send a mail to you when there are new Google results for such query.